# I'm working on a VHDL , and i am getting error in a DMUx process

Tags: vhdl

Error:"Keyword 'end' expected." and "Design unit declaration expected."

The process code is :

```
DMux: process(Din, A)
    begin
        S1(0) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "00";
            else others => '0';
        S1(1) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "01";
            else others => '0';
        S1(2) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "10";
            else others => '0';
        S1(3) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "11";
            else others => '0';
    end process;
```

I can't see what am i missing in this example.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in the code, e.g. ";" after `when` condition, and missing "()" around `others => '0'`.  Note also that use of `when` in `process` requires VHDL-2008.  Update to code can be:

```
S1(0) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "00"
    else (others => '0');
S1(1) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "01"
    else (others => '0');
S1(2) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "10"
    else (others => '0');
S1(3) <= Din when A(1 downto 0) = "11"
    else (others => '0');
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved the problem; that way others can also see that the issue is closed.

Comment: how do i accept the answer? it's my first time using the site